# SQL: Return Null row if present, else return other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this following table

```
AccessId PK, 
UserId, 
SecurityId, 
SectionId (nullable)
```

If the user have multiple rows for the same securityId.

```
UserId | SecurityId   | SectionId
-------------------------------------
User 1 | SecurityId 1 | SectionId 1
User 1 | SecurityId 1 | SectionId 2
User 1 | SecurityId 1 | SectionId 3
```

I want the query to return all these 3 rows.
If we replace the last row Section Id with a Null value, I want the query to return only the row with the null value.

The thing is, if no SectionId is defined, the security is application wide. If a sectionId is defined, the security is applied to that specific Section.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, can you post your existing queries and their results.

Comment: do you need to retain the rows where sectionID is not null if another row with the same userid/securityID has a null value in sectionID?  If not, you can delete those rows and querying isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thy this `or` condition. The equation (`=`) will fail when `@sectionid` is `null`, so there you need the second condition:

```
select *
from   table
where  sectionid = @sectionid
or     (sectionid is null and @sectionid is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's two separate queries - use a union and an condition that ensures only one side of the union is returned:

```
select * from mytable
where SecurityId = ?
and SectionId is null
union all
select * from mytable
where SecurityId = ?
and SectionId is not null
and not exists (
    select * from mytable
    where SecurityId = ?
    and SectionId is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from dbo.Table t
where t.SecurityId = @SecurityId
order by case when t.SectionId is null then 0 else 1 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @t table (AccessId int identity, UserId int, SecurityId int, SectionId int)

insert into @t (UserId, SecurityId, SectionId)
values(1,1,1)
, (1,1,2)
, (1,1,3)
, (2,1,1)
, (2,1,Null)

select *
    from @t
    where AccessId not in 
    (
    select t.AccessId
        from @t t inner join
            (
            select AccessId, UserId, SecurityId, SectionId
                from @t
                where SectionId is null
            ) secnull on t.UserId = secnull.UserId and t.SectionId = secnull.SecurityId
)
```